# Compressed air in a volume: Can I determine its temperature?

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas, density

Using a compressor, I augment the pressure in a volume (using atmospheric air). I only measure the pressure inside. I now that the density will increase however, the temperature decreases. Can any one give a hint how can I calculate any of the two if the only known values are the volume and the pressure.

Comment: Never seen  $ P*V = n*k*T $ ?

Comment: In deed. , but don't have n !

Answer (score 2):

A few clarifications on this thread in case anyone is reading in the future and is getting confused.

> I know however, that the temperature did in fact change, hence it's not an adiabatic process.

That isn't really how an adiabatic process is defined.  The temperature can change within a system (and often does) and it still be adiabatic.  An adiabatic process is simply one where no heat is transferred across the system boundary.  So if the compression of the gas is really quick, you can look at the state before and after compression and assume the system is adiabatic since not enough time will have passed for any meaningful amount of heat to transfer out of the system through conductive heat transfer.

> Adiabatic refers to constant entropy

A constant entropy process is simply referred to as "isentropic".

Comment: I think your second statement need to be expanded. Here is a very related discussion: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152924/change-in-entropy-adiabatic-expansion

Answer (score 1):

Normally when compressing a gas the temperature increases.  If you assume adiabatic compression, the law is $PV^\gamma=k$, where $\gamma=\frac {C_P}{C_V}$ is the ratio of specific heats and is usually about $1.4$ for air.  Then, as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) $\frac {T_2}{T_1}=\left(\frac {P_2}{P_1}\right)^{\gamma-\frac 1\gamma}$  This assumes you don't leak heat to the walls, probably not such a good assumption.

Comment: I know however, that the temperature did in fact change, hence it's not an adiabatic process. When I fill the volume, then release the air, sens it, I notice it became colder with respect to ambient temperature. IT is hence the increase in density which compensated.The question is how can I calculate the increase in density, decrease in temperature, based on the known fixed volume, and pressure

Comment: Adiabatic refers to constant entropy, so the temperature does change as shown above.  An approximation to what happened is you compressed the air heating it as shown.  Then it contacted the walls of the tank and cooled to room temperature.  When you let it back out, it cools from the expansion.  You can use the same formula as above, but the initial conditions are room temperature and the pressure in the tank.  The final temperature will be cooler than room temperature and will be about what you feel.

Comment: Interesting,but assuming the air became cooler once it is released,i still find it a very short time to loose maybe more then 10degrees

Comment: It is hard to judge how quickly the air will lose heat to the tank.  It loses some in the hose from the pump to the tank, where there is a lot of surface area.  I promise you it doesn't cool on pressurization but on depressurization.